# Biblatex only reverses first author's name

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I have the following MWE.bib:

```
@report{MWE,
  title = {Testing},
  number = {05-0124},
  institution = {{tex.SE}},
  type = {Working {{Papers}}},
  author = {Doe, John and Doe, Jane and Else, Someone},
  date = {2005}
}
```

I also have the following .tex:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber,giveninits=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{MWE.bib}
\begin{document}
    \nocite{MWE}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The output I get is:

[image]

Why is only the first author's name reversed (Last, First), while the other authors' names aren't? Is there some additional option I need to pass to `biblatex`?

Comment: Have you tried to add `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}` to your preamble?

Comment: This is a very standard style, and is the default ordering.

Comment: @AlanMunn In my field, PubMed-related, I saw this style in some journals but is not very standard, in fact is rarely used. I have no data to support this affirmation but is enough pick randomly some articles from this huge database  to note that.

Comment: In the Chicago Manual of Style He saith "Thou shalt revert only the first name" (14.18 "For a book with two authors, note that only the first-listed name is inverted in the bibliography entry.")